# Moving a debian system to another computer: problem with software raid

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, mdadm, software-raid

I have moved my hard discs (with a working debian stable system on it) from a computer which had hardware problems to a new, similar one. I would like to have the old system running on the new computer, but I'm having problems with software raid.

It seems that GRUB recognizes everything, but after a few seconds after the star of the booting sequence, I have the following error:

> mdadm: no devices listed in conf file were found

But if I boot the system with a knoppix live CD, I can correctly reassemble the raid array and I can access all the files on it.

Which conf file is wrong? What could I do to fix the problem?

This is my `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file:

`CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes
HOMEHOST <system>
MAILADDR root
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=... name=voyager.0`

The UUID array is the same as the UUID reported by `blkid` when run from the debian rescue system.

Command `grub-install` given from the recovery system exits with no errors.

Some more information: an inspection made at the `(initramfs)` shell shows that `/proc/partitions` is empty: disks are not recognized. `/dev` doesn't contain any files named `/dev/sd?` nor `/dev/md*`. But if I boot with the Debian Recovery disk, then the raid array is automatically rebuild and the boot partition (which is on another drive) is recognized.

The command `mdadm --examine --scan`, given from the Rescue CD, gives the following output:

`ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=9cd0e36b:c6cf5152:8806546f:fda3be1d name=voyager:0`

I have tried reinstalling GRUB over `/dev/sda`, over `/dev/sda1`, over `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` (the last two disks are members of the raid array, while `/dev/sda` is the boot drive, which isn't member of the array, but with no success. After `update-grub` I have the same error: `mdadm` can't see the drive array. The only difference that I can see between the Rescue system, which works, and my system, which is not able to see the raid device, is the linux kernel: the rescue uses version `4.9.0-6-amd64`, my system uses `4.9.0-4-686-pae`.

Comment: Check `/etc/fstab` and other configuration files that manage block storage and devices.

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/mdadm.conf` to your question. Have the device names (`/dev/sda` and so on) changed compared to the old system?

Comment: What disk controllers do you have on the old and new machines? Have you also moved interface cables from the old machine to the new one? If you move the disks back, does everything work again?

Comment: Issue the `cat /proc/partitions` command at the `(initramfs)` prompt you're dumped at when the system fails to boot end check whether your disk drives are recognized at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76651/discussion-between-zar-and-roaima).

Comment: Is LVM built into the initramfs? The boot environment won't see any logical volumes to initiate the array without it.

Comment: I haven't specifically used LVM in my orevious installation, which worked fine on my old computer. So, I don't know if LVM is built into the initramfs.

Comment: Also, I have tried with the i386 Rescue, but with the same results